# Conditionally disable button in ngFor in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to disable buttons that the logged in user have voted on, however, when I use the disabled directive inside my ngFor (in the example below) all of the buttons are disabled, not just the items that include the logged in user.  My goal is to check to see if an array contains the current user's uid, if so disable the button.  How can I achieve this?  Thanks in advance

compontent.ts:

```
this.itemsCollection = this.afs.collection('food', ref => ref.orderBy('voteCount', 'desc'));
          this.items = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
            map(actions => actions.map(a => {
              const data = a.payload.doc.data();
              const id = a.payload.doc.id;
                  this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
                    if(user) {
                       this.user = user.uid;
                        if (data.votedBy.includes(user.uid)){
                         console.log(id);
                         console.log('you already voted');
                         this.disabledButton = true;
                         return false;
                              }
                    else {
                        this.disabledButton = false;
                         }
                }
                });
              return { id, ...data };
            }))
          );
```

html:

```
<div class="firestoreLoop" *ngFor="let item of items | async" >
        <div class="container1">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                <p>{{item.voteCount}}</p>
                <p>{{item.id}}</p>
                <p>{{item.votedBy}}</p>
                <p>{{user}}</p>
                </div>
            <button type="button" id="item.id" class="btn"(click)="upvote(item.id)" [disabled]="disabledButton">Upvote</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Edit:  I got the desired result by adding `*ngIf= "user != item.votedBy"` to the button.  Thanks for the help gentleman.

Comment: For sure all buttons will be disabled since you are using the same variable , To do what you need you either reset ``disabledButton`` to its  initial value or just create an array of  ``{ ID: "" , isEnable: ""}`` for each user and then use ``*ngIf`` to detect it for each one

Comment: I like this idea.  Let me try to implement it real quick

Answer (score 1):

best way for you is to add `disabledButton` as a `property` of `item` in `items` array,
and then the `[disabled]` on the `button` should be `[disabled]="item.disabledButton"`.

And then you can control which item should be `disabled` by simply identifying the user and setting its corresponding `item's` `disabledButton` property to `true` otherwise `false`

Comment: So, I am already storing an array of user id's that have already voted, could I use that in its current form somehow?

Comment: This idea worked using *ngIf.  Thanks for the inspiration!